# Sitecore scheduled publish module compatibility with Publishing Service

Tags: publishing-service

Is Sitecore [Scheduled Publishing module](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx) compatible with Sitecore Publishing Service?

Did anyone try this one 8.2 application which has Sitecore Publishing Service?

Comment: Include a link to the specific module you are referring to.

Comment: are you refering to : https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx?sc_lang=en ?

Comment: Hi, I'm referring to below module in marketplace https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Scheduled_Publish.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I have not experienced any issues with the Hedgehog Sitecore Scheduled Publishing and the Sitecore Publishing Service, also it works for me on Sitecore 9.